# Whose boat got hit by the missile?

Tags: reference, taxi-2

In the French movie *[Taxi 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxi_2)* (2000)

> a missile is being fired at the special Peugeot during the police's terror parcours. The missile is being rerouted by the Atlas system and appears to hit the boat/ship of someone (presumably somewhere in the Mediterranean sea).

As common in the franchise, this is most likely a reference to something.

Whose boat is it? Or what is the reference about?

As a reminder: [Here's the scene.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?reload=9&v=yToRKw8rRKE&t=220)

Comment: You description make me think of the Pirate running gag in Asterix. But I don't remember making the connection when seeing the movie 18 years ago, so it was not that obvious.

Comment: Interesting, I never knew that _Taxi_ (2004) is a remake of a French film.

Comment: @Gendolkari I'm kinda biased in that, but watch the original tetralogy. They're super fun, and way, way, _way_ better than the remake :)

Comment: @GendoIkari there are a few movie remakes that were originally French movies. Two that come to my mind are: 1 "Just Visiting" (2001) and it's original "Les visiteurs" (1993), this one is strange as Reno and Clavier have the lead roles in both versions. 2. "Jungle 2 Jungle" (1997) and "Un indien dans la ville" (1994). In all 3 cases the French original is way better (personal opinion)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Out-of-universe: scriptwriter cameo

Allociné, one of the French "reference" sites about movies, [lists](http://www.allocine.fr/film/fichefilm-23460/casting/) scriptwriter Luc Besson as the "boat owner" (as a cameo). I didn't find an interview or something confirming this, and all the further articles mentioning the cameo seem based on Allociné's page. I'm not great at recognizing faces, but there is a similarity, when comparing to this photo from 2000, the year *Taxi 2* was released (photo source: [INA](https://fresques.ina.fr/europe-des-cultures-en/fiche-media/Europe00282/luc-besson.html)).

[image: Side-by-side comparison of the movie boat owner and Luc Besson]

## In-universe: he's no one

In-universe, the guy appears to be just a playboy with no luck on this day. The missile had to go somewhere and it made for a funny joke (and a cameo occasion).

The guy doesn't come back in any of the *Taxi* movies, and even in Marseille's history (the city where most of the *Taxi* movies take place), I don't know of any particular boat-owner guy the franchise would have been very prone to make a joke about.

Comment: Thanks! At first I had a hard time believing the two people on the images are the same, but after looking some interview snippets with Luc Besson, I see more and more similarities. Also, why would Allociné just randomly make up that he's the owner of the boat? Great catch! And thanks for finally giving me closure on this open question!